# Capture five groups

Tags: regex

I've a log file with a lot of text.
I need to parse it and extract a particular tag.

```
EVENT- runningusername serverip port action result
EVENT- runningusername serverip port action result
EVENT- runningusername serverip port action result
```

I want to extract any result that match those condition:

- Start with the word "EVENT-"
- Capture/Group required info (all info are delimited with an empty space)

Sorry, I forgot to post my experiment. My regex work, but I know if there's a better way

My current regexp:

```
(EVENT- (\b[^\s]+) (\b[^\s]+) (\b[^\s]+) (\b[^\s]+) (\b[^\s]+))
```

Comment: if it isnt broken, don't fix it. theres not much else you could do to improve your current regex except for maybe changing your spaces to '\s+` in case it is delimited by more than one space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the text will always be space separated, you can simplify it like so:

```
\bEVENT- (.+?) (.+?) (.+?) (.+?) (.+?)\b
```

The `.+?` (non-greedy quantifier) will search for everything up to the next space.

https://regex101.com/r/gL6vM9/1